# Variable of Varchar is always NULL in my UDF in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am now using the function in SQL server 2008, I am trying to write something like

```
   create function [dbo].[GetDaysStringForPivot](@date varchar(10))
   returns varchar(7000)
   as
  begin
declare @date_pivot varchar(3000)
declare @week varchar(10)
    set @week = 'week 15'
    set @date_pivot = @date_pivot + @week + @date

  return @date_pivot
```

when I invoke the function the return value is always null. Through debugging I found the @date_pivot is not assigned anything. Strangely, it can assigned normally if I add a statement here

```
  set @date_pivot = ''
  set @date_pivot = @date_pivot + @week + @date
```

Anyone know why?

Thank for your notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are concatenating to a null, you need to assign `@date_pivot` something or you can `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` (which you can't do in the function).

```
When you concatenate null values, either the concat null yields null setting of 
sp_dboption or SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL determines the behavior when one expression 
is NULL. With either concat null yields null or SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL enabled ON,
'string' + NULL returns NULL. If either concat null yields null or 
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is disabled, the result is 'string'.
```

- [String Concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259202%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating values with NULL always is NULL.

Workaround:

```
declare @date_pivot varchar(3000) = ''
```

OR

```
set @date_pivot = @week + ISNULL(@date, '')
```